# read file from local storage using js

Tags: javascript

hi i'm using java script to read txt file from my pc.
i try to do it in 3 ways like that:

```
function readTextFile(file) {
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                    if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                        console.log(allText);
                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
        }
        console.log("1");
        readTextFile("text.txt"); //GOOD
        console.log("2");
        readTextFile("D:/Documents/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Yonit_web_services/test/text.txt"); //BAD
        console.log("3");
        readTextFile("file:///D:/Documents/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Yonit_web_services/test/text.txt"); //BAD
```

all of them are pointing at the same file 
i got an error like that:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Documents/Documents/Aptana%20Studio%203%20Workspace/Yonit_web_services/test/text.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. test.html:21readTextFile test.html:21(anonymous function) test.html:26

whay is that ? thanks.

Comment: JavaScript cannot access the local file system for excellent security reasons.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` has some restrictions with cross origin. That being said, for way you doing it, `D:/` and `file:///D:/` makes the file appear to be accessed outside the origin.

Comment: you need to use an <input type=file> to read local files in javascript. you choose the file, then run URL.createObjectURL(inpFile.files[0]); to get a url you can feed to your readTextFile() function as-coded. you can't hard-code a path in the input, the user must choose the file for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser does not allow to file access through javascript due to security reasons, find the link below.

[Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security)

But in HTML5 its possible via using File Upload/ Download, link
[File Uplaod/Download](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while back. I fixed it by opening Chrome through Windows command prompt with this parameter: `--disable-web-security`

Please note that this has security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The first method of reading the file:

`readTextFile("text.txt"); //GOOD`

is working because `"text.txt"` is a relative path in the same respect that if you had the file system:

```
\index.html
\img\img.png
```

img.png would be accessible to index.html in this respect you might be able to access files and folders in parent and parrent's parent directories by using relative path-ing.

from a windows command prompt you can test these relative paths with `dir` as follows:

```
REM Dir will show contents of current directory
Dir
REM Dir .. will show contents of parent directory
Dir ..
REM Dir ../.. will show contents of parent's parent directory
Dir ../..
```

the same path-ing *should* work in JavaScript

This being said, the restrictions on `d:/` and `file://D:/` are most likely for security reason. You might want to check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You Can always do one thing and that is put it on some url from where your application access it(only if it does not contain any secure information).